# How to start express server with node in react native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I tried to start my server file that contains my MySQL connection details with command sudo node server.js but I got this error:

```
pandat@pandat:~/Desktop/myapp$ sudo node server.js
[sudo] password for pandat: 
DEPRECATED use https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp
start
{ Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pandat/Desktop/myapp/server.js:19:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
  code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true }
```

Comment: You have a few hints in the logs about what's going wrong.(`DEPRECATED use https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp`, this one may be trivial). But have you tried `consider upgrading MySQL client` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use

```
npm install -g express-generator
```